# Show Bootstrap Alert on index?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

how can I become a Bootstrap Alert, when something goes wrong or right on my index.php ?
I will that Bootstrap shows me an Alert under

Can you help me for this?

Have thanks for your time and help.

here is the index.php
https://jens-bruening-fotografie.com/pages/index.php

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try like below,
while entering form data for contact request you can use like this,

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
  <strong>Success!</strong> Message Send Successfully.
</div>

<div class="alert alert-info">
  <strong>Info!</strong> Please fill below form.
</div>

<div class="alert alert-warning">
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Enter Detail Message.
</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <strong>Danger!</strong> Please enter email id , required.
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I have the bootstrap date in the index.php file. but it shows me all the time. how can I show this data. when the user is click the send button ? Can you help me, again ? Thanks for your time...